# Is it possible to run ProcessBuilder from an Android Service?

Tags: java, android, processbuilder

I've encountered very strange problem.
I have service which have to send command "input keyevent NUMBER".
I'm using ProcessBuilder to launch it. The strange thing is - when my Activity(the one I use to launch the service) is active, the commands are processed. Hovewer, when Activity is not on the foreground, the commands aren't doing anything! Why is is it so?

I'm thinking about creating JNI library with function which calls something like "system(whatever I'd like to call)". Is is a correct approach?

Comment: Why do you use a process to `mkdir` and `ls`? Do you know java has [File#mkdir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) and [File#listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles())?

Comment: It does not matter WHAT am I sending. In fact, I'm sending "input keyevent 87" - this is to switch to next song(KeyEvent method doesn't work for all players, only for a few).

Comment: Generally, it **does** matter, because if you can do something with java it doesn't make sense to involve a process. You should write real things in your question, update it and replace _"mkdir", "ls > /path/to/some/thing" etc._ with what you want to send, otherwise other users may answer that there is no need to use processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with ProcessBuilder. The problem was that the view that I attached to window by this service had FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE. So, any other shell commands like "mkdir" and "ls" were working correctly, and "input" was ignored only because the view didn't have focus. Removing the flag solved the problem.

Comment: I am trying to click camera button from foreground service using input keyevent command but it is not working. do you know the reason? volume up or down works when my application (activity) is in foreground but not when it is in background